# Is There a Way To Implement Static Friction in Pymunk

Tags: python, pygame, simulation, pymunk

My question is fairly simple: is there a way or workaround to implementing both static and dynamic friction in pymunk?

I understanding this issue is difficult but believe someone may have a solution to the problem in pymunk.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the friction that will be used in a pre_solve callback. So one way might be to use the default friction as dynamic friction, and then in the pre_solve callback check if the the delta between the two touching bodies velocities (I think you should only check the velocity perpendicular to the collision normal) are below some small value, and if so override the friction with whatever you need for static friction.

See http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.Arbiter.friction

Note that I haven't tested this myself, so its best that you test it yourself to know if it works as expected.